# getting Refactor this getter so that it actually refers to the field '_HHmmTimeFrom'

Tags: c#, sonarqube, prop

Am getting **"Refactor this getter so that it actually refers to the field '_HHmmTimeFrom'."** sonarQube error. How to refactor below code. Am getting error in **Get in HHmmTimeFrom prop and  Constant.TIME_00_00_00 in HHmmTimeTo prop**

```
    private string _HHmmTimeFrom;
    private string _HHmmTimeTo;

    public string HHmmTimeFrom
    {
        get
        {
            return
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TimeFrom) ? "00.00" :
                DateTime.ParseExact(TimeFrom, "HH:mm:ss",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH.mm");
        }
        set { _HHmmTimeFrom = value; }
    }

        public string HHmmTimeTo
        {
            get => (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TimeTo) || TimeTo == Constant.TIME_00_00_00) ? "24.00" :
                    DateTime.ParseExact(TimeTo, "HH:mm:ss",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH.mm");
            set { _HHmmTimeTo = value; }
        }
```

Comment: A property should work such that after calling `x.Property = y;` then `x.Property == y`. For your implementation of `HHmmTimeFrom` that's NOT true, hence the warning. What is `TimeFrom`? Why are you not just returning `_HHmmTimeFrom` from the propery getter?

Comment: Seems like `HHmmTimeFrom` should actually be setting `TimeFrom` instead.  Otherwise when you get it you will not get whatever was set.  Also it seems like you shouldn't allow it to set it to just any old string and should make sure it's an actual valid formatted time.  Or maybe it should be a readonly property without a `set`.